# Why does my query return spots for attributes, but not their values?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq-to-xml

I am reading an xml file and running a query that looks for any entries where 'meetsMark' = 1, and then checks those entries 'SUMMARY' elements, for 'sum' and 'number' attributes. The code seems to be finding the items correctly as the output shows an accurate number of returned 'sum' and 'number's per room. How do I return the value of the attribute without calling '.Value' though. When I use '.Value' it works, unless there are any entries that don't have those attributes, then I get a null exception. Below is my code, and xml snip.

```
  List<string> test = new List<string>(); 

          var groups = from x in doc.Descendants("GROUP")
        where (string)x.Attribute("meetsMark") == "1"
        select x;

        foreach (var subgroup in groups)
        {
            //adds the code for any rooms found as 'ROOM: (Name)'
            test.Add("ROOM: " + (string)subgroup.Attribute("code") + Environment.NewLine);

            test.Add("ITEMS:" + Environment.NewLine);

            var sums = from summary in subgroup.Descendants("SUMMARY")
                       select summary;

            foreach (var sum in sums)
            {
                test.Add("sum = " + (string)subgroup.Attribute("sum"));
                test.Add("number = " + (string)subgroup.Attribute("number"));                                       
            }
            //add a blank line at the end to seperate each room
            test.Add(Environment.NewLine);                                
        }

        var message = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, test);
        MessageBox.Show(message);
```

Here is the xml that it is reading.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GROUP id="GRP1">
  <GROUP id="GRP2" code="MAIN" meetsMark="0">
    <GROUP id="GRP3" code="Room1" meetsMark="1">
      <ITEMS>
        <ITEM id="ITM6">
          <SUMMARY sum="Room1-Item1-Sum1" number="1"></SUMMARY>
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM id="ITM14">
          <SUMMARY sum="Room1-Item2-Sum1" number="2"></SUMMARY>
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM id="ITM15">
          <SUMMARY sum="Room1-Item3-Sum1" number="3"></SUMMARY>
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM id="ITM15">
          <SUMMARY sum="Room1-Item4-Sum1" number="4"></SUMMARY>
        </ITEM>
      </ITEMS>
    </GROUP>
    <GROUP id="GRP4" code="Room2" meetsMark="1">
      <ITEMS>
        <ITEM id="ITM95">
          <SUMMARY sum="Room2-Item1-Sum1" number="1"></SUMMARY>
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM id="ITM96">
          <SUMMARY sum="Room1-Item2-Sum1" number="2"></SUMMARY>
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM id="ITM97">
          <SUMMARY sum="Room1-Item3-Sum1" number="3"></SUMMARY>
        </ITEM>
      </ITEMS>
    </GROUP>
  </GROUP>
</GROUP>
```

It will return the rooms, and it will show spots for each of the attributes that I'm querying for, but not their values. How can I get those values and avoid getting the null exception issue caused by calling .Value and having it hit an entry with no attribute matching the query?

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't contain `.Value` anywhere. Instead, it casts the attribute to `string`, which is what I'd do too.

Comment: @JonSkeet -  I was mentioning it just so people didn't come answer: just use .Value.

Comment: But it means there's no question at all here. You've shown exactly how you do it - you cast to string. It's not clear why you're asking *anything*.

Comment: No worries, Stefan answered it.

Comment: No, Stefan pointed out a *totally different* problem. Your question had *nothing* to do with `.Value`, and *everything* to do with getting the wrong results. Unfortunately you talked about getting an exception, which you wouldn't have had with the code you presented. Please learn from this, and make sure you ask your next question more carefully. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
foreach (var sum in sums)
{
    test.Add("sum = " + (string)sum.Attribute("sum"));
    //                          ^^^ not subgroup
    test.Add("number = " + (string)sum.Attribute("number"));
    //                             same
}
```

Comment: Oh my god it was just a matter of calling the right item. Thank you for pointing it out to me, I was really confused.

Comment: We’ve all been there ;-)